# How do I make the background image on my react app responsive?

Tags: css, reactjs

There is a black space where the IOS status bar is. I cannot figure out how to get that space to fill up using CSS.

Here [1] is a screenshot of how it looks on an iPhone when the webpage is loaded.

The status bar space does not inherit/match the background image or the background color.

This is the code down below that I have for the background image.

````
body{
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  background: url("./Components/Images/back.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
} ```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Lwp.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plOl7TNc89A

I'm not sure what your exact issue is since you didn't provide a working example (please update if this doesn't solve it), but it sounds a lot like the issue desribed in the video above. tl;dr is that images are inline elements by default and they put a default buffer below them to allow them to line up with the main parts of a line of text and not the parts of text that drop below the line on which text is written. To fix this, you can override the default display and use

```css
display: block
```

for your individual img element to remove space below the image.

Some other problems could be the presence of margin or padding on your element (set those to 0, if needed) or the way the image is saved. Re-save the image from your image software using save as an not as save for web.

Comment: What do you mean did I take a look at the image? Your url for the image in question is a relative path for a resource on your system. If you're talking about the stack.imgur image, that's a jpg. You're having an issue with a .png image so there's no way that you're even talking about the same thing. Additionally, you never included a link to anything that puts your issue in context. You've dropped it just now in a comment and then asked if I even looked at the image. No, because you never included it. Put some effort into your original post if you want people to help.

Comment: I was talking about the stack image, it is a screenshot of the website on an iPhone. My mistake I should have explained the context better. I'll make the fix right now. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

also, I'm not sure what your exact issue is but if it is concerned with the default spaces in css please add

```
*
{
box-sizing:border-box;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

to reset default properties I hope this helps